# Json string list is coming with empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, http-post

am passing a json string collection from Android device to .net MVC HttpPost method. my json string is like.

```
{"collection",[{"Name":"A","Age":"12","Class":"10"},{"Name":"B","Age":"12","Class":"10"}]}
```

My MVC control function is:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string[] collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Model.StudentBehaviour> stdbehaviour_list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.StudentBehaviour>>(collection);
            Lib.StudentModule.StudentManager.InsertStudentBehaviours(stdbehaviour_list);               
            return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json("exception", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

the function parameter value is

```
collection = "(Collection)"
```

expected value in collection is

```
collection[0] 
Name = A 
Age = 12
Class = 10
collection[1] 
Name = B 
Age = 12
Class = 10
```

please help to fix this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC has the concept of ModelBinding. This means that if you add parameters to an Action method, MVC will try to fill these with the data you send.

This means you can change your code to:

```
 // Example of your Student class. 
 // Make sure that all properties you want to bind to are public
 public class Student
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
     public int Class { get; set; }
 }

// Example of an Action method. Note that instead of taking a string as parameter,
// you just accept a collection of Student objects.
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(List<Student> collection)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json("exception", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

You can then use the following jquery to post your data:

```
function sendData() {    
        var data = [{ 'Name': 'A', 'Age': '12', 'Class': '10' },
            { 'Name': 'B', 'Age': '12', 'Class': '10' }];

        var collection = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/Create",
            type: "POST",
            data: collection,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        }).done(function (msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks Wouter de Kort , i will try this method, i have a quick question for you is the parameter name and the Json key should be same ? eg: if i pass {"Details": [{ 'Name': 'A', 'Age': '12', 'Class': '10' },
            { 'Name': 'B', 'Age': '12', 'Class': '10' }] . but my HttpPost function parameter name is collection is it make any problem ?

Comment: Yes they should be the same. ModelBinding works on matching parameter names to data found in your request.

Comment: Hi Wouter de Kort, am implemented the code which u given. But still getting as null . anything i have to do in Global.ascx.

Comment: hi , am getting the value if i have a single object like  {"collection",{"Name":"A","Age":"12","Class":"10"}}. but if am using am list then getting an null object.

Comment: You don't have to change anything in your global.ascx. I've tested this code in a new, default MVC project. What do you get if you change the parameter type from List<Student> to string and send multiple objects?